# How do you edit a HTML document permanently with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a very simple commenting section with JavaScript.

This is the form :

```
<form>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Leave your thoughts ..." id="theComment"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="text" id="commenterName" placeholder="What's your name?"/>
    <input type="button" value="Post Comment" name="postCommentButton" onclick="postComment();"/>
</form>
```

And below is the JavaScript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postComment()
    {   
        var node = document.createElement("p");
        var textComment = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("theComment").value);
        node.appendChild(textComment);
        var element = document.getElementById("commentDisplaySection");
        element.appendChild(node);
    }
</script>
```

But as soon as the **page reloads, the comments disappear**. How do you modify a HTML document permanently with JavaScript? Do I have to use PHP and MySQL for this ?

Comment: yes, you need to store the comments on the server somehow.

Comment: JavaScript is run after the page is rendered, and therefore (AJAX changes aside) quite temporary.

Comment: You could also use Java and text files, or CGI and... something... to write on.

Comment: I would [prioritize `.innerHTML` over `.appendChild()`](http://jsperf.com/html-innerhtml-vs-appendchild)

Comment: you can put your values in a PHP session, so it don't disappear on realod, but after the session expire

Comment: @JeffNoel, sorry I had deleted the comment before you replied.

Comment: @ahmad - session would be just as temporary

Comment: Not if you change the session expire time, i would suggest you using sessions

Comment: What about this site :

[link](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/add_comments_to_website.cfm)

I thought it uses JavaScript...

Comment: @SyafiHakim I would recommend coding one yourself instead pasting code without really understanding what it does.

Comment: Session? Are you nuts? Session is available only for the user who's using it, not for the others.

Comment: To me, the question is a little too broad to be answered precisely (flagged).

Comment: @MarkBaker at least, a real wise suggestion.

Comment: @MarkBaker Wouldn't localStorage not get the content of the other people that might leave a comment?

Comment: @JeffNoel I coded that one myself, I mean in the question one. So, did the site I mentioned uses only JavaScript?

Comment: Given that OP seems is asking about using a "locally executed" language, I suggested a local solution - this could be appropriate if OP wanted to make personal annotations to a page

Comment: MarkBaker, I get your point. @SyafiHakim The *widget* that you linked in the comments stores the data in its own db, try to take a look at the code within it: http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/8twZH/

Comment: Awesome, Awesome, Awesome. Detailed explanation. Thx in advance, at least I know that I need to use servers and databases. Cheer everybody !

Comment: @jeff as for the jsperf - try with `documentFragment`s. What matters here is one access to the DOM or ten.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to make permanent changes to a web page provided that the JavaScript is making an AJAX call to the server where a server-side script then applies the requested change.

Comment: Thanks in advance, at least I know that I need to use servers and databases. Cheer everybody !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @SyafiHakim! Consider accepting this answer (click the check mark next to the answer) if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Streams or sequences of bits representing the comments and their data **must** to be remembered(stored) somewhere -- so that they can be recalled and displayed by yourself, and others viewing the comments.

changes to DOM only live as long as the DOM itself. If DOM dies, changes die. And, DOM dies *all the time* (page loads/reloads).

So, if you can't store in DOM, where should you store? Hey wait, can you use cookies or localStorage? Maybe you can. Wait no you actually can't.

*Your* cookies live in **your** browser. And as long as your browser lets them live. Also, I can in no way see your cookies directly. So cookies are out. Same goes for localStorage -- it's local to you.

What else can we do? How about saving cookies on the server? Wait this could be it. Yes! This is it!

Think about it, 100% of the websites on the internet do this! They store data on a server that is available all the time, for anyone to access. Bingo!

So, in short, yeah use php/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can make MySQL table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `values` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
    `value` varchar(2000) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )
```

and then make a php script that will connect to the table, remember mysql_real_escape_string.
then you will have to connect to the place you want to output it, and connect to the same database and table, and get the values by username. remember to use htmlspecialchars. that's all i got. if you want to use ajax, you can do it here.